# SAML single SP multiple consumers/domains

Tags: php, saml

I have a case where my employer is creating a lot of different portals. Some portals will be on different domains and some on subdomains.

E.g. portal.com, sub.portal.com, other-sub.portal.com but also portal-a.com or portal-b.com.

All these portals belong to, are related to and maintained by my employer. Authentication at all these portals is done with SAML.

To setup SAML for each of these portals will be cumbersome since for each portal we have to:

- configuring a connection to some IDP (exchange metadata)
- on a yearly basis do a security checkup (as per IDP policy)
- pay subscription for connecting to IDP

As you can imagine this eventually becomes untenable and impossible to manage. We are programming mainly in PHP and hence we use the SimpleSAMLPHP library to do the hard work for us.

Would it somehow be possible to create one SP and let all the other portals go (authenticate) through that one?

Any advice on how to solve this problem? What would be a logical setup?

Answer (score 0):

Since your employer has multiple portal applications wants to authenticate using SAML protocol, you can have single Service Provider (SP) reverse web proxy server that communicates with external Identity Provider (IdP) and you integrate all portal applications with that single SP reverse web proxy.

All portal application requests will be routed to proxy first, then to SAML-SP, user authenticate at external IdP, SAMLResponse receive at proxy, forward SAMLResponse to SAML-SP and then user access the portal applications.

Refer Shibboleth reverse proxy for reference. (You can find similar thing for PHP).
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/4358260